# Stop form flashing briefly on screen when closing a second application instance almost immediately

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have an application which checks during the OnCreate of the main form if another instance of the application is already running by creating a mutex.  If it is then the second instance passes a message to the first, then closes itself down.  It works fine, except for a small niggle of the second application flashing it's main form briefly on the screen before it closes.

I have an ugly hack of starting the application with the main form WindowState set to wsMinimize, and then use a timer with a 1ms delay to maximise the form.  But this seems like a terrible hack.

Any better ideas?

```
procedure TMyAwesomeForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  h: HWND;
begin
  // Try to create mutex
  if CreateMutex(nil, True, '6EACD0BF-F3E0-44D9-91E7-47467B5A2B6A') = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  // If application already running
  if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then 
  begin 
    // Prevent this instance from being the receipient of it's own message by changing form name
    MyAwesomeForm.Name := 'KillMe';

    // If this instance was started with parameters:   
    if ParamCount > 0 then 
    begin
      h := FindWindow(nil, 'MyAwesomeForm');

      //Pass the parameter to original application
      SendMessage(h, WM_MY_MESSAGE, strtoint(ParamStr(1)),0); 
    end;

    // Shut this instance down - there can be only one
    Application.Terminate; 
  end;

  // Create Jump Lists     
  JumpList := TJumpList.Create;  
  JumpList.ApplicationId := 'TaskbarDemo.Unique.Id';
  JumpList.DeleteList;
  CreateJList();
end;
```

Comment: Move your code somewhere before the form is actually created, before the `Application.CreateForm` is called, in the *.dpr file.

Comment: This is very close to being a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15136960/62576). The answer there can probably help. (You're checking too late - by the time you've hit `FormCreate` it's too late to stop, and `Application.Terminate` simply posts a `WM_QUIT` message to the main window. You need to check for the prior instance in the `.dpr` file instead, before `Application.Initialize` has been called.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't perform your checks inside the form class, since the form is created it will show.

IMHO the better place to perform a check like yours is the .dpr file itself.

For example:

```
program Project3;

uses
  Forms,
  Windows, //<--- new citizens here
  SysUtils,
  Messages,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

function IsAlreadyRunning: Boolean;
var
  h: HWND;
begin
  //no comments, sorry, but I don't use comments to explain what the 
  //code explains by itself.
  Result := False;

  if CreateMutex(nil, True, '6EACD0BF-F3E0-44D9-91E7-47467B5A2B6A') = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then
  begin
    if ParamCount > 0 then
    begin
      h := FindWindow(nil, 'MyAwesomeForm');
      if h <> 0 then
        PostMessage(h, WM_MY_MESSAGE, strtoint(ParamStr(1)),0);
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  if not IsAlreadyRunning then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Rather post the message instead of sending, it may block this initialization if the message receiver hangs on its proceeding. Also cast the `wParam` parameter to the proper `WPARAM` type. And finally, `IsAlreadyRunning` is not a good name for function which doesn't even check if the window is found, it just sends the message even if the `FindWindow` returns 0 (NULL).

Comment: @TLama I just moved the code from the question to show where to avoid the form showing, but you're right, I was lazy, so I added a checking and changed to `PostMessage` instead of `SendMessage`. As per the cast to WPAREM, IMHO it's not needed, since the compiler always do it for you.

Comment: Thanks very much.  That's sorted it out.  I wasn't aware I could even put in code in the dpr file like that.  The joys of trying to teach yourself!  I tried to upvote your solution but sadly my reputation isn't sufficient.